# Moving between activities with updated info

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I have 2 activities . Activity 1 has Information. Activity 2 has a form to update Information in Activity 1 .
How can i return yo Activity 1 and show updated information ? 
When i move from activity to another should i use finish () ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also start another activity and receive a result back. To receive a result, call startActivityForResult() (instead of startActivity()).

For example, your app can start a camera app and receive the captured photo as a result. Or, you might start the People app in order for the user to select a contact and you'll receive the contact details as a result.

Of course, the activity that responds must be designed to return a result. When it does, it sends the result as another Intent object. Your activity receives it in the onActivityResult() callback.

[This the detailed link of about startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#StartActivity)

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern.. dont have to override back pressed it will automatically use the super method.. So, in **activity 1** use this field var..

```
  BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


       // update the info and UI here


    }
};
```

`onResume()` of **activity 1**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver ,new IntentFilter("info"));
```

and in **Activity 2**

```
Intent intent= new Intent("info");
intent.putExtras("infoss",*yourInfo*);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Note** The **activity 1** will be automatically updated with correct info .. you *dont need to use `onBackPressed()` logic for this*

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity

[image]

In the second Activity when your work is done and you want to send data from the second activity to the first activity

[image]

receive data in the first activity
[image]